# caesar encryption in C with undefined input

Tags: c, string, pointers, encryption

iam trying to write a simple caesar program in C.

The input i want to give should be with undefined lenght like in the program.

The problem i have is, when i enter a short string like "HELLO WORLD" in the encrypted string i have some random additions at the end. 
When i give a longer string as input the program crashes befor it starts to encrypt.

I have no idea where the problem could be, maybe some of you can give me a hand or have ideas what is crap here :/

Every advice is welcome thank you :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// realloc the size of memory for the user input
char *inputString(FILE *fp, size_t size)
{
  // the size is extendet by the input with the value of the provisional
  char *str;
  int ch = 0;

  size_t len = 0;
  str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size); // size is start size

  if(!str)
    return str;

  while(EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n')
  {
    str[len++] = ch;
    if(len == size)
    {
      str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 16));
      if(!str)
        return str;
    }
  }
  str[len++] = '\0';
  return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
} 


// lowercase letters
void makeLowerCase(char *input)
{   
  while(*input != '\0') // "while(*input)" would also work
  {
    *input = tolower(*input);
    input++;
  }
}

// test function
// character length of the input
int lengthOfInput(char *input)
{
  int len = 0;
  while(*input != '\0') // "while(*input)" would also work
  {
    len++;
    input++;
  }
  return len;
}


// encrypts the input caesar
char *encrypt(char *toBeEncrypted, int caesarNum)
{   
  int tmp = 0; // going through the input
  char *tbE;

  for(;*toBeEncrypted != '\0'; toBeEncrypted++, tmp++)
  {
    *(tbE+tmp) = *toBeEncrypted + caesarNum;
    printf("%c", *(tbE+tmp));
  }
  return tbE;
}


// ------------------------------------------------------
//                      main
// ------------------------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
  char *s; // input from user
  char *encryptedString; // encrypted input/output
  int loi = 0; // length of input

  srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); // initialize random value for encryption
  int caesar = (rand()%25) + 1;  // random number for caesar encryption

  printf("input string : "); 
  s = inputString(stdin, 10); // realloc the memory space for the input

  makeLowerCase(s); // convert to lower case
  printf("lower case: %s\n",s);

  loi = lengthOfInput(s); // length of the input
  printf("lenght of input: %d\n",loi);
  printf("caesar number: %d\n",caesar);

  encryptedString = encrypt(s, caesar); // encryption
  printf("\nencrypted : %s",encryptedString); // output

  free(s);
  free(encryptedString); // free the memory
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc`/`realloc` memory for `tbE`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i've changed it so far

Comment: You forgot about the NUL-terminator. `char *tbE = malloc(sizeof(char)*lOI);` → `char *tbE = malloc(sizeof(char)*(lOI+1));` and before `return tbE;`, add `tbE[lOI] = '\0';` or `tbE[i] = '\0';`. Also, I've rolled back your edit as it made my comment as well as the answer by Michael meaningless.

Comment: @CoolGuy Now it is working. I didnt get no more issues. 
Was wondering at first why you add 1 to lOI, but yeah for sure.... makes sense with the '\0'
Many thanks for helping and for the rollback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized variable.

```
// encrypts the input caesar
char *encrypt(char *toBeEncrypted, int caesarNum)
{   
  int tmp = 0; // going through the input
  char *tbE;

  for(;*toBeEncrypted != '\0'; toBeEncrypted++, tmp++)
  {
    *(tbE+tmp) = *toBeEncrypted + caesarNum;
//    ^
//    ^ here tbE is used, but it has never been initialized
//
    printf("%c", *(tbE+tmp));
  }
  return tbE;
}
```

---

There may be more issues.

**Side note**

In `encrypt` the loop should be written with array indexes rather than with pointer arithmetic for the sake of readability:

```
for(i = 0; toBeEncrypted[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
  tbE[i] = toBeEncrypted[i] + caesarNum;
  printf("%c", tbE[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

With freeing the memory i thought i have to free them both because i have to "different" pointers. 

Is it irrelevant which of them i free - s or enryptedString?

Comment: @A7GPS0 Of cours it crashes if you initialize it to NULL. You must allocate memory with `malloc`.

Comment: Is there any advantage, apart from readability, if i write it with arrays instead of pointer arithmetic?